# Dummy variable interaction

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction, interpretation

Consider the following model:

$wage_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1male_i + \beta_2private_i +u_i$

where $male_i=1$ if male; $0$ if female, and $private_i=1$ if private school; $0$ if state school.

The **base group is females from state schools**.

So when $male_i=1$ and $private_i=1$, the coefficients $\beta_1 + \beta_2$ measure the average wage differential of males from private schools compared to females from state schools.

But now suppose we add an **interaction between the two dummy variables** into the model so that:

$wage_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1male_i + \beta_2private_i + \beta_3male_iprivate_i+u_i$

So now when $male_i=1$ and $private_i=1$, **what do the coefficients $\beta_1 + \beta_2 +\beta_3$ measure?**

**What is the interaction between these two dummy variables adding to the model?**

Thank-you!

Comment: See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/interpretation-of-interaction-term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that $\beta_1>0, \beta_2<0, \beta_3>0$.
$\beta_1$ says that wage is higher for men.
$\beta_2$ says that wage is lower for people (irrespective of gender) from private schools.
$\beta_3$ says that wage is higher for men from private schools (but lower for women from private schools, when $male_i=0$; even lower than for women from public schools.)

Comment: So the dummy variable interaction is subdividing the group of private school students into male and female?